# Android custom progress bar component

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a progress bar that automatically slides up when incremented. I've sorted the sliding bit (using java), but now want to create a custom progress bar component. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Smooth_Progress_Bar extends ProgressBar{

public Smooth_Progress_Bar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }
}
```

I'm using this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.todddavies.content.smoothprogressbar.Smooth_Progress_Bar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/pb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I get an immediate force close :/

I strongly suspect I'm doing something majorly wrong with the java bit. I promise to tick the right answer!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that you get from LogCat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a project using your code, with the exact same code (even the Object name "Smooth_Progress_Bar").
It all compiled and ran fine.
So this leaves:

You may need all three of the constructors, eg:

```
public Smooth_Progress_Bar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public Smooth_Progress_Bar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public Smooth_Progress_Bar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

or your problem is in your `progressDrawable`. If you drawable is xml, it may contain errors. Try the constructors and if that doesn't work, examine your drawable.

Comment: He doesn't need all three. He only needs one of the two constructors that have the AttributteSet argument.

Comment: True - I was being lazy. The middle one would do.